# LogHandler flush vs direct output in publish

Tags: java, logging, handler

I'm currently writing an own `java.util.logging.Handler`, and I dont really understand the concept there...
I have my publish method here which contains the logic to see if a `LogRecord` should be shown, a `Formatter` (or just `SimpleFormatter` if the `.getFormatter() == null`) and finally i put the formatted String into a Cache.

Now i wrote the `flush()` Method and I'm getting in trouble here: The `flush()` Method is never called by Java, so when an Error occured, its not shown. I put a call of `flush()` into my `publish()` Method and now i can see the log messages... So i dont see the conecept here? When should `flush()` called and by whom? Or do I have to make it like i do it now, and call `flush()` by my own in the publish() Method?

If you take a look to this example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/HowtowritecustomLoghandler.htm they dont even to anything with the `flush()` Method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a bit late now but for the benefit of others...

Im seeing something similar, and assumed similar behaviour to you

I had a look at the usages of it and it seems to be a way to do a flush in a standard way, and seems to be guarantee you will be flushed on close more than anything.

Some people "flush themselves", I suppose guaranteeing that superclasses can benefit from the flush as well also.

Finally since there is no threshold control on this flush and since Im not seeing it being called in debug sessions, or code to call it I don't think Java gives us anything in this regard.

Comment: np! yeah java logging is awful!